# Why do i keep getting page not found error

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to solve this problem but it keeps showing 'page not found' whenever I run the program.

Here is the problem, I am using python and Django to write a message in a browser but I keep getting the page not found error.

Here is the code for views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')


def news(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here is the news')
```

and here is the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

path('', views.index),
path('news', views.news)

]
```

In my browser, if run http://127.0.0.1:8000/products it prints the output 'Hello world" but whenever I run this http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/news or http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/new it shows page not found error and I change my code of urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news)
]
```

it get executed. So i don't know what's wrong with the code.
Thanks.

Comment: welcome. can you  edit your question so the code is more easily read? You'll need to show all of your urls.py urlpatterns. You need a urlpattern for each path you want to respond to. So if you don't have /products/new you'll get a 404.

Comment: please add whole traceback.